# get the file name of the csv while parsing mutliple files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I am trying to go through a folder containing multiple CSV files and combine them into a single larger file. To do that I want to copy the info in the CSV along with its name (ie. foo from csvfiles/foo.csv) into a new CSV. How do I get the name of the CSV that I'm reading from as I read the whole set?

I am using

```
IFS=","
files=/CSVFiles/*
cat $files|while read col1 col2
do
echo $col1 $col2
done
```

I just need to get the name of the specific file that col1 and col2 are from. I tried putting the while loop inside a a `for f in $files` but got an unspecified error. Any ideas?

Comment: one idea: `for fname in /CSVFiles/*; do while IFS=, read -r col1 col2; do echo "${fname} ${col1} ${col2}";done < "${fname}"; done`

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
cd CSVFiles

awk -F , -vOFS=, '
FNR == 1 {
    f = FILENAME
    sub(/\.csv$/, "", f)
    print f
}
{print $1,$2}' *.csv
```

You can use `f` where you want, eg. like `{print f": "$1,$2}`.